# Visual Basic 2008 開発言語は.net におけるWriteAllTextで書き込みできない場合がある

Tags: .net

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllTextの関数を使用して、Stringの内容をファイル出力しております。

グリッドの情報をカンマ区切りで出力するような感じで出力をしているのですが、途中データが抜けてしまう事が発生してしまいます。

再現性は100%ではなく、端末にも依存している可能性があります。

```
Dim fileName as String = "C:\work\output.csv"

for i as integer = 0 to grid.RowCount -1

　Dim strData as String = GetData()

　My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(fileName , strData , True, Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis"))

Next
```

出力したいデータ数が600だった場合、実際に出力されるデータ数が598や599となることがあります。

抜けてしまう、データについては、毎回同じではなく規則性はないように見受けられます。

GetData()と別の関数にてデータ取得したものを書き出ししているのですが、strData.lengthをログ出力した際には、0とはならなかったことから、データは取得出来ていると認識しております。

StreamWriterで代用をしましたが、同様の現象が発生しました。

StreamWriterの場合は、For文内で、Open/Closeを行って試しました。

何が原因で、対策としては何が良いのか、わからないため、質問させていただきました。

2021/09/27 テスト用のコードを作成しました。

```
'既存の出力したいファイル(一つのファイルに順次追記をしていきます)
Dim writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(vFile, True, Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis"))
writer.WriteLine(strLine)
writer.Close()

'デバッグ用のコード
'ファイル名にグリッドの情報を使用して生成してStringの情報をファイル書き込み
Dim wFileName As String = i + 1 & "_" & .Item(0, i).Value & "_" & .Item(1, i).Value & ".csv"

'StreamWriter
Dim testWrite As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(wRoot & wStrWriterPath & "\" & wFileName, True, Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis"))
testWrite.WriteLine(strLine)
testWrite.Close()

'FileSystem WriteAllText
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(wRoot & wFileAllTextPath & "\" & wFileName, strLine, True, Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis"))

'File WriteAllText
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(wRoot & wFileAppendPath & "\" & wFileName, strLine, Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis"))
```

上記3つの方法で出力しました。
個別出力グリッドの1行1ファイルでは、全行の出力が確認できておりますが、
1つのファイルに全行出力の場合は、2行抜けてしまうケースがありました。
グリッドの情報は全部で830行となります。

個々の出力においては、830個のファイルが出力されており、データも存在しているが
1ファイル全行出力のファイルにおいては、828行しか存在してませんでした。

Comment: 試しに`WriteAllText()`ではなく、事前に自分で`strData`を`Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis").GetBytes(strData)`で`byte[]`型データに変換して`WriteAllBytes()`で書いてみた結果と比べてみてはどうでしょう？ それか書き出す前の`strData`の長さだけではなく内容も含めて別途記録しておいて、書き出した結果の`"C:\work\output.csv"`と比べてみるとか？

Comment: あげられたコードであれば `grid.RowCount` が期待する行数を示していることは確認されていますでしょうか？ そもそもループ回数が不足していれば、`WriteAllText` 等の書き込み手段に関係なく、不足するはずです。

Comment: > kunif様
回答ありがとうございます。
Byteデータによる書き込みは試しておりません。
ただし、自分の端末では、処理を行っても現象が起きず、すべて期待通りにデータ出力されます。
現象が発生する端末にて、試すことができれば確認してみたいと思います。

Comment: > sayuri様
回答ありがとうございます。
ループの回数については問題ありません。
strDataのレングスが0でないことを確認(ログ出力により)し、WriteAllTextを実行したのですが、追記されないケースがありました。

strDataが設定されているが、WriteAllTextを実行してもデータが書き出されないことがあることが、不思議でなりません。

Comment: ログで確認できているのであれば、消えた行も特定できるのではないでしょうか？ 消えた行の規則性などありましたが、質問に追記されると解決につながるかもしれません。当然理解されていると思いますが、600行出力したいとしても、ログに599行分の記録しかなければ、出力されるファイルにも599行分しか含まれていないはずです。

Comment: > sayuri様
期待値が600行の場合、ログは600行であるが、出力されるファイルには、599行分しかないケースが発生してます。同じデータを複数回出力した場合に、600行分出力されるケースと、599行分しか出力されないケースが発生してます。

Comment: 現状は「ファイルI/Oの何らかの問題」あるいは「開示されていない範囲(GetData関数他)のアルゴリズムの問題」の区別がつきません。試しに、Forの外でStreamWriterを作り、ループ内ではStreamWriterに追加していくだけとした場合に問題が発生するかどうかを何度か検証してみてはどうですか？

Comment: > Azurlean様
回答ありがとうございます。GetData関数については、問題ない事を確認しました。
デバッグ用に同一ループ内で、別ファイルに1ファイルごとにグリッドの行の情報を書き出すようにしましたが、StreamWriterの追記をしているものには、書き出されず、以降のデバッグ用のtestWriterにおいては、書き出しされていました。

Comment: 書き出されなかった行は何行目でその内容は何かは特定できていますか？ それらが何か規則性や特徴、環境依存性等があるかを調べてみてはどうでしょう？ あとは再現する物ならMicrosoftのフォーラムとかフィードバック窓口に質問してみると進展するかもしれません。

Comment: 現状は「ループ内で頻繁に開いて書いて閉じるを繰り返すと正常動作しないことがまれにある」ということになります。それが環境固有の問題なのか、Windowsなどの不具合なのか定かではありませんが、「ループ内で対処する」を続ける限り、対策困難でしょう。「ループ内で追記＆都度オープン」はMUSTなのですか？

Comment: > kunif 様。書き出されなかった行のは特定できています。規則性、特徴等は確認してますが、わかってません。

Comment: > Azulean 様。ファイルの書き出し処理を変更しました。My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText()にて、都度追記するようにしましたが、同様の事象が発生しております。この場合は、都度内部でオープン処理を行っているとは思いますが、明示的にOPEN/CLOSEは行っていないため、OPEN/CLOSE問題については要因から外れるかと思います。

Comment: 私がリスクある行為とみなしているのは、「瞬間的に何度も同じファイルをOpen/Closeしていること」です。WriteAllTextは内部的にOpen/Closeしています。暗黙的・明示的、間接的・直接的を問わず、非常に短い時間の間に同じファルのOpen/Closeは無駄が大きいので避けるべきだと主張しています。

Answer (score 1):

まず.NETはソースコードが公開されています。

- [`FileSystem.WriteAllText`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.10/src/libraries/Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core/src/Microsoft/VisualBasic/FileIO/FileSystem.vb#L776-L819)
- [`File.AppendAllText`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.10/src/libraries/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs#L554-L567)

両メソッドを試されていますが、どちらも内部で`StreamWriter`を呼び出しているに過ぎません。もちろん

- [`StreamWriter`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.10/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs)

も公開されています。リンクは.NET 5.0のものであり、質問はVisual Basic 2008（.NET Framework 2.0～3.5辺り）でバージョンは異なりますが、基本的な実装は同じです。
（以前は.NET Framework 2.0以降のソースコードも公開されていましたが、配布が終了してしまいました…。）

---

で、この`StreamWriter`はファイルI/Oの基礎であり、とてもバグがあるとは思えないというのが正直な感想です。例えばAzuleanさんが頻繁なOpen/Closeを避けるべきという提案をされています。もちろん頻繁なOpen/Closeを避けるべきというのは正しいですが、その一方で、たとえ頻繁であれ何らか問題が発生したのであれば`StreamWriter`は例外を投げる設計になっています。現状、例外が投げられていないのであれば、そのような問題は発生しておらず、指示通りの動作をしているはずです。
（その意味では`On Error Resume Next`で例外を無視していませんよね？）

それよりはこの手の質問でありがちなのは、質問の範囲外に原因があるケースです。最初にコメントしましたがループ回数が想定と異なっているとか、それ以外にも、出力されたファイルの行数の数え方に違いがあるとか、エンコーディングが不正になっているとか、ウイルス対策ソフトがファイルの内容を書き換えてしまったとか。これらは思いついた例の一部であり、個々に否定されても意味はありません。可能性は無限にあり、それらは質問者さんにしかわからない内容です。

そんなわけで`StreamWriter`その他の動作を疑うよりは、その外側に目を向けることをお勧めしたいです。質問者さんとしては納得しかねるかもしれませんが、当サイトはQ&Aの蓄積が目的であり、その趣旨からすると質問者さんと同様に`StreamWriter`等を疑っている方には有益と判断し、この回答を投稿します。